# MOSFETs Cascode Configuration

Tags: mosfet, powermosfet

The following schematic is from Texas Instruments: http://www.ti.com/tool/PMP10195

I have some questions on it:

1. Is Q1 always on? How do I calculate the voltage that the gate sees? It looks like this voltage is defined by R1, R2, R4, D7, and D8.
2. The documentation says:  *"In order to reduce the stress on the FET, a cascode configuration has been selected"*. What I understand from this is that Q1 and Q2 share the big VDS voltage, right? However, as Q2 is the one activated by the IC U1, and Q1 seems like is always on, Q1 is protecting Q2, not viceversa. Am I right?

I'm needing a MOSFET which withstands very high VDS voltage (>1kV), so I'm wondering if this configuration is reliable and cheaper than just a single 1.2kV MOSFET that are really pricey.

Note that I'm not asking for specific product recommendation. I'm just asking from a general design point of view.

[image]

Comment: I don't know about reliable or cheaper, but I can say that 1.2kV MOSFETs were not alwa and have not always existed. There was a time where they simply were not an option. And what if you wanted to do something with MOSFETs that was more than 1.2kV?

Comment: what pulse SafeOperatingArea will you need?